# Inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got REF

Tags: oracle, ref

```
CREATE TYPE empresa_type AS OBJECT (
    CNPJ INTEGER, 
    nome_fantasia VARCHAR2(30), 
    pais VARCHAR2(25),
    fundacao DATE
)

CREATE TYPE funcionario_type AS OBJECT (
    CPF INTEGER, 
    nome VARCHAR2(30), 
    sexo CHAR(1), 
    nasc DATE,
    empresa REF empresa_type
)

CREATE TABLE empresa_tab OF empresa_type (PRIMARY KEY(CNPJ))
CREATE TABLE funcionario_tab OF funcionario_type (PRIMARY KEY(CPF), FOREIGN KEY(empresa) REFERENCES empresa_tab)
```

report error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got REF MY_WKSP.EMPRESA_TYPE

Comment: I can't reproduce your error; on my system, running Oracle 12.2.0.1, all statements execute without error. What is your Oracle version? Run `select banner from v$version`, the first row in the output should tell you your exact Oracle version.

Comment: Oracle Database 18c EE Extreme Perf Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the table and then add a `SCOPE` to the reference (rather than trying to define it as a foreign key, because it is not):

```sql
CREATE TABLE funcionario_tab OF funcionario_type (
  PRIMARY KEY(CPF)
);

ALTER TABLE funcionario_tab ADD SCOPE FOR ( empresa ) IS empresa_tab;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d124e88cb0b26f0417430547e6f8168)*

Comment: The same error happens if I do it this way.